# Timing issue (?) between python, bash and psql

Tags: python, bash, postgresql, psql

I use Pythons `os.system`, `pg_dump` and `psql` to transfer data between Postgresql databases. The command is execute like this:

```
os.system('set some variables ; pg_dump ... | psql ...')
... process copied data ...
```

So I set some required environment variables, then dump the required data and pipe it to psql which sends it to the new database. This works fine most of the time. But when the copied data becomes large, it looks like the script continues with processing the copied data, before the actual import has finished.

I know that piped commands are executed in subshells. So is it possible that os.system returns, before the command in the subshell has finished? Any hint how to solve or at least how to debug this, would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the shell command will only return when the commands have finished.

But the PostgreSQL *server* may still be finalizing the commit by the time the command line utilities have completed. It is running as a separate process and by the time Python connects to the database it could be that the transaction is not yet visible to other connections.

Without knowing more about the imported data it is hard to give you a one-size-fits-all solution on how to detect if the import transaction has committed yet. Pausing the Python process (with `time.sleep()`) could be a work-around, or you can test for specific data in the database, and loop until that data appears.